# What is Imaginary in Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, continuous-signals, frequency-domain, fourier

How to plot graph of $e^{-t}$ in frequency domain. What would be the axis? If its Fourier transform is $1 /(1+j\omega)$, then how can we plot imaginary on frequency domain (amplitude vs frequency graph) .

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot

Comment: Or [Visualizing Functions of a Complex Variable](https://www.pacifict.com/ComplexFunctions.html)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in order to have a Fourier transform, the original signal has to be multiplied by the unit step function:

$$x(t)=e^{-t}u(t)$$

Giving indeed the transform:

$$X(\omega)=\frac{1}{j\omega+1}$$

The way to plot a complex function on the frequency domain is by finding both its amplitude and its phase, and drawing one graph for each.

For the amplitude case, find $|X(\omega)|$, which is:

$$X(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega^2+1}}$$

Comment: You can directly enter Latex formulas using dollar signs (check the changes I made).

Comment: Excellent, thanks!